# Force iframe to load as the last element

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, iframe, load

I have a website that uses AJAX to load the page content. On the home page I have an image slider, some other elements, and an iframe that contains a playlist. For some reason the iframe loads slowly and the image slider won't load until after the iframe is fully loaded. Is there a way to force the iframe to load after the image slider so that it won't take so long to load?

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: This is the url: wrbbradio.org
If you need something specific I can find it.
I've played with some things to get the pagespeed to an 81/100 on googles pagespeed insights so I don't think it should be taking as long as it does

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to load the playlist after the images have loaded by getting rid of the playlist in the HTML and appending it after the images have loaded using:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
  $(".textwidget").append('<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:1229877582:playlist:2sOytopsJKw2Xk4U3K79uP" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>');
}
```